# How to verify if all elements of a list are equal

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a result in a list form: `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

How to verify if the elements are equal?
If I use `Equal` doesn't works with a list.
So, the result is:

```
`{1,2,3,4,5,6}`
```

If I use:

```
Equal[{1,2,3,4,5,6}]
```

Doesn't works.

How to catch just the numbers, like this?

```
In[479]:= Equal[1,2,3,4,5,6]

Out[479]= False
```

Comment: try `Equal@@{1,2,3,4,5,6}`?

Comment: or `!DuplicateFree`

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot.